# Can I add factorygirl factories to shared gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, factory-bot

I have a set of active_model models I've extracted into a shared gem. I want the gem to also contain their factories for use in rspec tests defined in any of the projects that are using the gem to avoid defining the same factories in each project.  Is that possible?

Comment: How did you manage to handle this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share the factories that I have in a GEM and use it in other project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700345/how-can-i-share-the-factories-that-i-have-in-a-gem-and-use-it-in-other-project)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah its possible. You can place the Factories inside your gem. Lets say lib/gem/factories/. Then your other gems can include the factory.

For example when you create the gem 'awesome_gem', you could have the followin structure:

`` |-- lib
|   |-- awesome_gem
|   |   |-- module1
|   |   `-- version.rb
|   |-- factories
|   |   |-- factory1.rb
|   |   `-- factory2.rb
|   `-- awesome_gem.rb
|
`-- spec
   |-- awesome_gem
   `-- spec_helper.rb ``

Where lib contains your gem code and specs contain your specs. 
awesome_gem.rb would define your gem includes such as awesome_gem/version.rb and more includes. However its recommended not to include the factories directory, since an user of your gem could not be using factory_girl.

Once the gem is packed, they can use require awesome_gem/factories/factory1.rb in their tests. Note that you need to specify your factory path in your spec helper to include your shared factories. Note that this solution is not tested, and paths that need to be included may be different. Also you can place the factories directory outside the lib dir, as long it is included by your .gemspec .

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: @EkiEqbal, here you go. see message above.